# Efficient method to add a column to a listcolumn in r

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, tibble

How can I create a new column within a listcolumn? I can only do it by mutating into a new listcolumn.

Moreover, I find that the double mutation below is quite slow compared to the other methods. Does mutate add a lot of overhead?

```
library(repurrrsive)
library(tidyverse) 
#> ── Attaching packages ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse 1.2.1 ──
#> ✔ ggplot2 2.2.1     ✔ purrr   0.2.4
#> ✔ tibble  1.4.2     ✔ dplyr   0.7.4
#> ✔ tidyr   0.8.0     ✔ stringr 1.3.0
#> ✔ readr   1.1.1     ✔ forcats 0.3.0
#> ── Conflicts ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
#> ✖ dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
#> ✖ dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()

system.time(rep(
  gap_m<-gap_nested %>% 
  mutate(new_list=
           map(data,~ .x %>% mutate(pop_str=str_sub(pop,end = 4))))))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   0.087   0.005   0.091


system.time(gap_c<-gap_nested %>% 
              mutate(new_list=
                       map(data,~ cbind(.x,pop_str=str_sub(.x$pop,end=4),stringsAsFactors=F))))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   0.017   0.000   0.017

system.time(gap_b<-gap_nested %>% 
              mutate(new_list=
                       map(data,~ bind_cols(.x,pop_str=str_sub(.x$pop,end=4)))))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.02    0.00    0.02
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do what you do but save the result back to the `data`:

```
mutate(.df, data = map(data, .f))
```